# Github API does not return all repositories

Tags: python, repository, github-api

I am accessing the names of all Python-based repositories in Github using the API. However, my script only return 1020 repos. When I checked the github website, it results are > 900000. Am I missing something here?

```
def get_names(response):
    content = json.loads(response.text)
    return [it['full_name'] for it in content['items']] 

query = dict(q="language:python",sort="stars",order="desc",per_page=100)

# Loop through results pages, get names
response = requests.get('https://api.github.com/search/repositories', params=query,headers=header)

names, idx = [], 0
while response.ok:
    names.extend(get_names(response))
    if 'next' in response.links.keys():
        idx += 1
        print('Getting page {0}'.format(idx))
        print response.headers
        response = requests.get(response.links['next']['url'],headers=header)
        sleep(2)
    else:
        break

print "Total Github-Python Package:",len(names)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can find in the [documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/):

> To satisfy that need, the GitHub Search API provides up to **1,000
>   results for each search.**

So this is an expected behavior. You're just lucky to get 1020 instead of 1000 :)

Comment: yes..i found someother way to scrape the metadata - i retrieved the records by weeks

Comment: Sure, strict filter is a way to go